# Python pandas looking for the equivalent value of a DataFrame to another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file in which I need to look for a value in a column and check whether it is existing in another column using Python Pandas. Here is how it looks:

```
svc_no   i_status   caller_id   f_status   result     remarks
11111    WO         22222       WO         Not Match  Transpose
22222    WO         11111       WO         Not Match  Transpose
```

Here are the conditions:

- In a row, `svc_no` is not equal to `caller_id`
- `svc_no` is in `caller_id` but is in a row with different number
- `svc_no` and `caller_id` is not equal to `NULL` or `n/a`
- `result` is equal to `Not Match`

If the conditions are met, then I should write `Transpose` in the `remarks` column

I used `.loc` and `isin()` but somehow, even if the `svc_no` is not in `caller id`, assuming *svc_no* and *caller_id* are not equal, it still writes *Transpose* to `remarks` column.

Here is my code:

```
df.loc[(df['svc_no'] != 'NULL') &\
       (df['caller_id'] != 'n/a') & \
       (df['svc_no'].isin(df['caller_id'])) & \
       (df['caller_id'].isin(df['svc_no'])) &\
       (df['result'] == 'Not Match'),
       'remarks'] = 'Transpose'
```

Comment: Your task is not clear. You are a programmer (I assume), so express it in clear, complete, and unambiguous terms: IF this, this and this THEN do this.

Comment: Ok. I will edit it and make it clear.

Comment: look at the third and fourth lines of your query. There is a typo in them (a comma instead of a period), but also a parenthesis is misplaced. It may be the reason for the error. Please fix it before we get any further.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the error. The query above was not copy/pasted form the original source so I did re-typed it. It was a typo. Sorry sbout that.

Comment: You still have the oddly placed parentheses. They _may_ be the cause of your error. Please fix them and check if the trouble is gone.

Comment: Thanks again. Fixed the misplaced here and I still receive same icorrect output in my data.

Comment: I applied the code in your example to the dataframe in your example (with an extra row that has svc_no of 44444 and caller_id of 33333), and it correctly identified the rows to be marked as Transpose. Make sure that your production code exactly matches the example. The example is correct.